# Setting up on click for Floating action button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a FAB in my activity_main and I have 5 ViewPager fragments.Fragments have RecyclerView. How do I access this RecyclerView from Main activity and set on click method for FAB so that on clicking FAB, recyclerview in the active fragment scrolls to top.I tried using `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` inside fragment.But it doesn't work for all fragments.I have this inside fragment.Should I place the following in main activity.java? How to access RecyclerView and scroll it to the position 0 on clicking FAB in a fragment?

```
public void setFloatingActionButton(){
    fab = (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and easiest solution is to use EventBus.

Two best EventBus libraries for Android are [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto). I use otto.

All you need to do is register the bus in your fragment where recycle view is placed. And write a method e.g

```
public void scrollToStart(){
 //body here.
}
```

Subscribe the above method to the bus like this.

```
@Subscribe   // subscribing an event to the bus.
public void scrollToStart(ScrollToStartEvent event){ //you need to create an event class e.g ScrollToStartEvent
 //body here.
}
```

Now FAB onClick Listner.

```
public void setFloatingActionButton(){
    fab = (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) 
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BUS.post(new ScrollToStartEvent()); //NOTICE
        }
    });
}
```

Note : All I did is posted an event, in your case `ScrollToStartEvent()`. Bus will check if any method is subscribed to this event and will call that particular method. You've to read EventBus documentation to understand this correctly.

**Pros :** Much less code and more readable code. Complex objects can be passed through (no object serialization is required).

**Cons :** You'll need to learn how to use EventBus.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I set up the FAB onClick in the activity and here is how I did it. I have conditional actions based on which fragment position is being viewed.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.fab:
            if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                Toast.makeText(this,"First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Second",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

In my example I only have 2 fragments so I hard coded the 0 and did an if else. In your case I would use a switch within the switch. Also a good way to organize all the fragments would be with a `private SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> fragmentMap = new SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>>();`

you would include this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    Bundle bundle = fragment.getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey(KEY_FRAGMENT_POSITION)){
        int position = bundle.getInt(KEY_FRAGMENT_POSITION);
        fragmentMap.put(position, new WeakReference<Fragment>(fragment));
    }
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}

public Fragment getFragment(int type){
    WeakReference<Fragment> weakFrag = fragmentMap.get(type);
    Fragment frag = null;
    if (weakFrag != null)
        frag =  weakFrag.get();
    return frag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when an Activity event gets lost in the chain due to the way that XML or events are structured the bellow is the best structure to ensure the events go to the right places.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(LOG_HEADER,"onClick");       
        }
}

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        ll.setOnClickListener((MainActivity)getActivity());
        return ll;
    }
}
```